# Spring Boot JWT authorization/authentication

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, post, cookies, jwt

I am trying to build backend for register and login, but I do not know how can I create JWT for user after login in or sign up, Can You suggest me what I should do? My goal is to login/register via postman and after this the JWT would be created for user. For now I do have post method for login and register and they work(I do even have the BCrypt for password). I use mongo DB compas for this project.

```
   package com.beauty.springapplication.model;

   import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
   import lombok.Getter;
   import lombok.Setter;
   import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
   import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
   import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
   import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

   @Document(collection = "users")
   @Getter
   @Setter
   public class User {
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    private String name;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private boolean isAdmin;

    public User(ObjectId id, String name, String username, String password, String email, boolean isAdmin) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
        this.isAdmin = isAdmin;
    }
}
```

package com.beauty.springapplication.model;

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;

@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class LoginRequest {
 private String email;
 private String password;
}
```

```
package com.beauty.springapplication.controller;

import com.beauty.springapplication.error.InvalidEmailOrPasswordException;
import com.beauty.springapplication.error.UserAlreadyExistsException;
import com.beauty.springapplication.error.WeakPasswordException;
import com.beauty.springapplication.model.LoginRequest;
import com.beauty.springapplication.model.User;
import com.beauty.springapplication.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping("/registration")
    public User registerUser(@RequestBody User user) throws UserAlreadyExistsException, WeakPasswordException {
        return userService.registerUser(user);
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public User loginUser(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) throws InvalidEmailOrPasswordException {
        return userService.loginUser(loginRequest.getEmail(), loginRequest.getPassword());
    }
}
```

```
package com.beauty.springapplication.service;

import com.beauty.springapplication.error.InvalidEmailOrPasswordException;
import com.beauty.springapplication.error.UserAlreadyExistsException;
import com.beauty.springapplication.error.WeakPasswordException;
import com.beauty.springapplication.model.User;
import com.beauty.springapplication.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class UserService {
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;
BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

public User registerUser(User user) throws UserAlreadyExistsException, WeakPasswordException {
    if(!userRepository.existsByEmail(user.getEmail())) {
        if(user.getPassword().length() < 6) {
            throw new WeakPasswordException("Password is Not Strong Enough");
        }
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        return userRepository.save(user);
    } else {
        throw new UserAlreadyExistsException("User Already Exists");
    }
}

public User loginUser(String email, String password) throws InvalidEmailOrPasswordException {
    if(userRepository.existsByEmail(email)
            && passwordEncoder.matches(password, userRepository.findByEmail(email).getPassword())) {
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    } else {
        throw new InvalidEmailOrPasswordException("Incorrect Password Or Email");
    }
}
```

}

```
package com.beauty.springapplication.repository;

import com.beauty.springapplication.model.User;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, ObjectId> {
    boolean existsByEmail(String email);

    User findByEmail(String email);
}
```